# javascript window.location issue with IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have some strange behavior on my window.location redirects in IE and Firefox as part of my angular application. When calling window.location = xyz the first time it works fine in IE/FF/Chrome. On the second call which is supposed to go to google.com, Chrome does what it's supposed to, but IE and FF don't do anything. In the IE web console I can see that the navigation was triggered but the page and URL hasn't changed in my window. Now if I press F5 on this page it goes to the page it's supposed to even though the URL at the top is not pointing there (both in IE and FF).

Has anyone ever encountered this problem and knows how to solve it? I've tried all versions of redirecting (window.location, window.location.href, windows.location.assign(), window.location.replace() and also the angular service $window) with no luck.

First call triggered from a button press (working fine in all browsers):

```
$scope.pressButton = function() {
  var url = 'xyz/index.html';
  $window.location = url;
};
```

Second call triggered by a keypress (only works in Chrome):

```
function exitModule() {
  $window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
  console.log('window.location'); // still pointing to the old page
}
```

---

**Update with code calling the exitModule() function:**

Note: The application is built with angularjs.
The exitModule() function gets called in all browsers, it's just the redirect which doesn't happen in IE/FF.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-keydown="keyPress($event);">
```

JS:

```
// Handle global key press
$scope.keyPress = function(event){
  if(event.which === 27) { // EscapeKey
    exitModule();
  } else {
    $scope.$broadcast('keyPress', event);
  }
};
```

Comment: why `$window.location` instead of `window.location`?

Comment: The $window is just a wrapper service around window provided by the AngularJS framework.

Comment: could you provide the code used to capture events?

Comment: [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/twc9bcxo/) works correctly on latest versions of FF and IE.

Comment: I've added the capture event code. Unfortunately it works in your example. It seems something is just off in my code as the code to capture the event works just fine it's just not changing the page. I was hoping someone might has seen this behavior before (not changing but changing after refresh) and could point me in the right direction of what could be interfering in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the issue and I'm aware that it was almost impossible to figure this out without having the full code available. The above code was a bit simplified therefore it was missing the problem. The function exitModule gets called as soon as a promise is resolved. The call looks like this:

**Correct**

```
dataService.saveModule().then(exitModule);
```

My code was as shown below with the brackets after exitModule which is wrong. I don't quite understand the behavior of FF/IE compared to Chrome though ...but that's for another day.

**Wrong**

```
dataService.saveModule().then(exitModule());
```